# codeigniter custom 500 error

Tags: codeigniter

At this very moment I do not have any 500 error being thrown, but in case I ever do in the future I'm trying to customize a page so users never see that awful white screen.

I am having trouble adding said page. I have the page made and a controller that loads the page, but when I try and route the page in the route file or route it using .htaccess I'm still getting that white screen.

This is what I have tried in my route file

```
$route['500_override'] = 'notFoundErrorPage/serverError';
```

and then this is what I have tried in my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://writeyourfiction.com/NotFoundErrorPage/serverError
```

any help would be wonderful!

Comment: 500 errors indicate a server failure of some sort. Trying to load a page that requires a bunch of PHP to execute before displaying will likely not work. If you want a custom 500 page, you will likely have to create a static HTML page.

Comment: alright, and if I have that static page how would I call it? I placed it in the errors folder and am calling it in the .htaccess as such errors/500Error_view, but for some reason it still cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter does not have any custom error handlers aside from `404_override`, so using one for any other HTTP code will be fruitless.

[Apache has custom error pages](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html) as you've already attempted, but there are a couple of things to note that may be affecting your results:

**1: A local URL begins with a `/`**

> A local URL to redirect to (if the action begins with a "/").

**2: Specifying in an .htaccess may require additional configuration:**

> It may be used in .htaccess files if AllowOverride is set to FileInfo.

If you seek additional help, either here or elsewhere, please provide more information about your server environment: operating system, web server (e.g. Apache) and version, any relevant add-ons or modifications you may have made, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server software you are using. If you are using Apache, see here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html

If you aren't using apache, google "[webserver software] custom 500 page".

If you're still having trouble, try asking on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I will go over there and ask because I still cannot load a custom page.

Comment: Make sure to include what server software you are using in the question!